# Nesting arrays in Realm with Swift

Tags: json, swift, realm, nsarray

I have read several examples on SO on how to store arrays of data to Realm. Still, I am not finding a particularly clear example.

In short, I have a (simplified) JSON as below which I would like to store in Realm. How can I add an array of ingredients to Realm, so that it is contained within an array of menuItems?

```
{
   "menuItems": [
      {
         "name": "name 1",
         "ingredients": ["ingredient 1", "ingredient 2"]
      },
      {
         "name": "name 2",
         "ingredients": ["ingredient 1", "ingredient 2", "ingredient 3"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have my realm models set up as such:

```
class MenuItemsRealm: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    var ingredients = List<IngredientItemsRealm>()
}

class IngredientItemsRealm: Object {

    @objc dynamic var ingredientItem: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, you're stating that a `menuItem` object has a property/variable called `ingredients` and it contains an array of `String`. What you probably want to do is create a **array of Objects** that contains the specific `ingredientItem` property/variable.

To exemplify your JSON would be something like this:

```
{
   "menuItems": [
      {
         "name": "name 1",
         "ingredients": [
             {
                 "ingredientItem": "item name"
             }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```